# php login help for final project

Tags: php, html

So I am trying to make a valid login for my web dev class' final project. Whenever I try to log in with the correct credentials, I always get redirected to the "something.php" page, and I never receive any of the output that I put in my code. This even happens when I input valid login credentials.I know this isn't a secure way to do a login, but this is for final project purposes only. I've attached all of my files below (minus pictures), even though you probably don't need all of them.

The something.php file (the php for the login)

```
<?php
$action = empty($_POST['action']) ? false : $_POST['action'];
/*var radio = document.getElementById('radio');*/

switch ($action) {
    case 'login':
        $username = empty($_POST['username']) ? '' : $_POST['username'];
        $password = empty($_POST['password']) ? '' : $_POST['password'];
        if ($username=='test' && $password=='pass') {
            setcookie('userid', $username);
            $response = 'Login: Sucess';
        }
        else {
            $response = 'Login: Fail';
        }
        print $response;
        break;
    case 'get':
        $userid = empty($_COOKIE['userid']) ? '' : $_COOKIE['userid'];
        if ($userid=='test') {
            $response = 'Todays special are organic Brazilian strawberries $1.75 a pound';
        }
        if ($username!='test' || $password!='pass'){ 
            header('Location: XXX/something.php');
            echo "username and password combo are not valid";
            //radio.value = "logged out";
        }
        print $response;
        break;        
    case 'logout':
        setcookie('userid', '', 1);
        print 'Logged out';
        break;
}
?>
```

login.html page

```
<div class="group">
<div id="radio">
<form id="radio" action="">
  <input type="radio" name="select" value="login"> Logged In<br>
  <input type="radio" name="select" value="logout" checked> Logged Out<br>
</form>
</div>
<form id="content2" class="itemBlock">
<p> Don't have an account? Sign up here!</p>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
  E-mail: <br>
  <input type="text" name="email"><br>
  Password: <br>
  <input type="text" name="password"><br>
    <br>
     <input type="button" value="Register" onclick="addToCartFxn()">
</form>

<div id="center">
<form id="content" class="itemBlock" action="something.php" method="post">
    <br> <br>
  E-mail: <br>
  <input type="text" name="email"><br>
  Password: <br>
  <input type="password" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" class="get" value="Login" id="login">
    <input type="submit" value="Logout" id="logout">
</form>
    </div>
</div>
```

final.php page

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Content via Ajax</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">-->
<!--<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>-->

  <script>

  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
      beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.jqXHR.fail(function() {
          ui.panel.html(
            "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. ");
        });
      }
    });
  });


    $(function(){
        $('#login').click(function(){
            $.post('something.php', 
            {
                action: 'login',
                username: $('#username').val(),
                password: $('#password').val()
            },
            function(data){
                $('#center').html(data);
            });
        });
        $('#logout').click(function(){
            $.post('something.php',
            {
                action: 'logout'
            },
            function(data){
                $('#center').html(data);
            });
        });
        $('.get').click(function(){
            $.post('something.php',
            {
                action: 'get'
            },
            function(data){
                $('#center').html(data);
            });
        });
    }); 

    function addToCartFxn() {
        alert("This feature is coming soon!");
    }

  </script>

    <style>

        #floatright {
            float:right;
            }


        #header{
            background-image: url("tree rocks header.jpg");
            width: 100%;
            height: 200px;
            padding-top: 1px;
            text-align: center;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position-y: 3255px;
            background-position-x: -2112px;
        }

        #headertext {
          z-index: 100;
          color: white;
          font-size: 72px;
          font-family: exo, arial, serif;
        }


        @font-face {
            /* Declare the name of the font (we make this value up) */
            font-family: exo;

            /* And where it's located */
            src: url("Exo-Medium.otf");
        }


            .addtocart{
            background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
            border: none;
            color: white;
            padding: 7px 12px;
            border-radius: 7px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 3px;
            }

        #radio {
        float: right;    
        }

        #content {
            font-family: exo, arial, serif;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 25px;
            background-color:forestgreen;
            align-content: center;
        }

        #content2 {
            font-family: exo, arial, serif;
            float:left;
        }

        #logout{
            margin: 5px;
        }

        #login{
            margin: 5px;
        }

        .itemBlock{
            display:inline-block;
            margin: 10px;
            border: 2px black;
            border-style: solid;
            text-align: left;
            padding-left: 5px;
            padding-right: 5px;
    }

        @font-face {
            /* Declare the name of the font (we make this value up) */
            font-family: exo;

            /* And where it's located */
            src: url("Exo-Medium.otf");
        }    

        #center{
            margin-left: 42%;
        }


        body {
           min-height: 100%;
            height: auto! important;
        }

        .group:after {
            content: "";
            display: table;
            clear: both;
        }

    </style>

    </head>
<body>

<div id="header"> 
    <p id="headertext"> Claw's Cache</p> 
    </div>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1"> Our Products </a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2"> Available Produce </a></li>
      <li id="floatright"> <a href="login.html"> Login</a></li><!--tabs-3's content is being put there by ajax-->
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
      <p>Listed here are all the current vendors that are associated with us products.</p>

<?php

//Use glob function to get the files
//Note that we have used " * " inside this function. If you want to get only JPEG or PNG use
//below line and commnent $images variable currently in use
$images = glob("*.png");
$i=0;

//Display image using foreach loop
foreach($images as $image){

echo '<div class="itemBlock"> <a href="'.$image.'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$image.'" height="250" width="200" /></a> <br>';
echo '<button type="button" class="addtocart" onclick="addToCartFxn()"> add to cart</button> </div>';    
}
?>           
  </div>

  <div id="tabs-2">

<p>Our available produce page is being updated currently! 
<br> <br> As a placeholder, we have attached a video that many of our customers recommend to every person interested in indoor gardening.</p><br>
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RWCIaydwM_w" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>

  </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

At line

```
$action = empty($_POST['action']) ? false : $_POST['action'];
```

You read a POSTed form field called 'action'. I can't find that field in any of your web forms... Maybe give a name to your SUBMIT buttons are retrive that instead. Action is an atribute of the web form, not a field name.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like it's ignoring your jquery login code because your form is submitting when you click `Login`, and since you're checking if `$_POST['action']` is empty

```
$action = empty($_POST['action']) ? false : $_POST['action'];
```

it fails because you don't have any form element with that name. the `form`'s `action` attribute only specifies to which page to send the data.

I think you might try adding `onsubmit="return false"` to your `form` in order to get it to only use your `$.post` method.

```
<form onsubmit="return false" id="content" class="itemBlock" action="something.php" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you amend your opening variable assignment to

```
empty($_POST['action']) ? $action = false : $action = $_POST['action'];
```

I'm not 100% sure why this happens, but I know from past experience that the shorthand `IF` statements can give some unexpected results.

On top of this, it doesn't look like you are setting the `$_POST['action']` field anywhere?

If you are referring to the method of transmit specified in the opening `<form>` tag, then this is wrong.

If your shorthand `IF` statement is used to determine how data is being passed into the `something.php` file, then you could do

```
empty($_POST) ? (empty($_GET) ? echo "No User Data Passed" : $data = $_GET;) : $data = $_POST;
```

(I know it seems long winded, but the extra check for $_GET data can be omitted, it is simply there as a proof of concept type check).

From that, the `$data` variable will be set with either the $_GET or the $_POST user defined data from the forms on the other pages.

I hope this helps.